# Deep zoom with JavaScript (non flash OpenZoom)

Tags: javascript, wordpress, zooming, deepzoom

I created a Wordpress plugin to add hi res photographs and split them into tiles, but my javascript front end is very slow. I would like to know if there is an open source tiled image zoomer (similar to OpenZoom but in JavaScript)?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, check out [Seadragon Ajax](http://gallery.expression.microsoft.com/SeadragonAjax).